# how do i calculate user inputs in form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a rails app with user inputs, i have to perform a calculation and store its new value. eg of price is given which was earlier written in js and php

```
if(count($_POST['price']) >= 0 && !empty($_POST['price']))
{
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $sql .= " '". $price ."', ";
    switch ($price){
        case ($price >= 0 && $price <= 21):
            $price_rating = 0;
            break;
        case ($price >= 22 && $price <= 29):
            $price_rating = 5;
            break;
        case ($price >= 30 && $price <= 39):
            $price_rating = 7;
            break;
        case ($price >= 40 && $price <= 49):
            $price_rating = 8;
            break;
        case ($price >= 50 && $price <= 59):
            $price_rating = 6;
            break;
        default:
            $price_rating = 0;
    } 
}
else
{
    $price_rating = 0;
    $sql .= " '', ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

everything is the same... in the according controller you just need to do

```
@price = params[:price] (which is the same as $price = $_POST['price'];)

if (0..21).include?(@price)
 @price_rating = 0
```

if ... and so on